# position number in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a question regarding matlab. If I have a vector v=[ 4 5 2 3 0 7]
and I want to write an equation that include the position number of each element in the vector v. For example, I want to have the the number "1" in an equation and that number changes as I loop the vector from v(1) to v(6) so whenever I want to use the "4" in the vector v, I want a command to output number "1" because "4" is the first position(element) of V. and if I want to use "5" I want it to output a "2" because "2" is the 2nd position of V which is what "5" is at. How this make sense and can anyone help? I have only been learning matlab for a few months. thanks!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
v = [4 5 2 3 0 7];
[~, w] = sort(v);
```

Then `w(4)` is `1`, `w(5)` is `2` etc, as desired.

Comment: Thanks Luis, it's getting close to what I try to figure out. So for the sort command you had up there, what if I have a vector of all "zero"s and "one"s. such as v=[0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]? basically I have a matrix of 10 by 10 and it has randomly placed "1"s and "0"s. I wrote a code to plot a wind farm where each "1" represents a turbine location, but the problem is I can't figure out how to link that 10 by 10 matrix to my plot. I have posted a separate question on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

`find(v==4,'first')` returns the position of the first `4`.

Comment: sorry about the confusing description. I will try a better way to describe.Basically I have a vector v=[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]. I want to map each element in this vector to a location on a 3x3 square grid. the square grid starts on the bottom left corner at origin (0, 0) and the top right corner is at (600, 600) so the square grid is divided into 9 cells and each one is 200 long by 200 tall in the coordinate. and then for each element that has the value of 1 in the vector V, I try to plot a dot on the grid. so I am writing a for loop to loop through each one of the nine element in v.

Comment: so if you imagine the 3 by 3 grid and the bottom left cell is cell 1 and the one on its right is cell 2, the one on top of cell 1 is cell 4, then the top right corner cell of the grid is cell 9. which matches the 9 elements in my vector v. so for each number of "one" in the vector I want to plot a dot in the grid in the co-responding cell of the element.

Comment: since I want to plot the dot in the middle of each 200 by 200 cell, I write an equation for the x coordinate of each element of the vector as x_cor=(position#-floor(position#/3)*3)*200-100. This gives me an x location of 100 for the first zero in the vector and x location of 300 for the 2nd zero in the vector. This is the only way I can think of to map my vector to a x-y coordinate system so I can plot a "turbine" at which ever the location of the element that has a number "one" in it. so I am trying to find out how to get the "position #" such that it is "one" for the first zero in the vector

Comment: and the position # would be "two" for the second "zero" in vector v. However if there is any easier ways to map a vector to a coordinate system that would be even better but from my search I couldn't find any help on it. Please let me know if this clarifies it a little or made it worse :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't know do I get what you mean but you want something like this ? 
*>>v=[ 4 5 2 3 0 7]*

*>>i=find(v==5)*

Comment: Hi Garry, what I mean is say for this vector v, v(1)=4 since that's the first element in v, but I want v(1)=1, and v(2)=2, and v(3)=3. how would I achieve that?

Comment: How can you get v(1)=1, v(2)=2 and v(3)=3? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Hi Parag, I am trying to find a command that can give me 1 for the first location of vector v, and give me 2 for the 2nd location of v because I am trying to map the vector to a x-y coordinate system so if matlab sees certain number in the vector, it will plot a "star" in the coordinates of that element. So if I have 9 elements in vector V then there would be a 3 by 3 square grid with each one of the 9 little square represent each element in my vector V.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't too clear.  But from some of the comments, maybe this will work:

For vectors, you can do:

```
v = 1:5; %Or whatever end number you want
```

which will result in v(1) = 1, v(2) = 2, ..., v(N) = N.